# INDOOR NAVIGATION app in Augmented reality

Tags: augmented-reality

I am trying to build an indoor Navigation app in augmented reality, where path to a destination will be shown to a destination.
Problem is I am not able to find where to start and what to do. I have taken the various destination GPS coordinates.But what to do next ? I am thinking to use mapbox but new  to everything. What should I do?

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for this, If yes, then give some link..